# Protractor does not see dynamically insertered html

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have to insert HTML into view dynamically. Inserted code contains angular directives. I found the way to do this using directives:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/e4zrusgw/
```

I would like to create e2e test using Protractor. Unfortunately Protractor does not see elements from dynamically inserted HTML. For example, if inserted code contains

```
<button>Cancel</button>
```

and I try to get access to this button in protractor specification:

```
element(by.buttonText('Cancel'));
```

I get:

```
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Piotrek.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The solution is to use browser.driver object, for example:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('accept-button'))
```

instead of

```
element(by.id('accept-button'));
```